# Pulling last years data from a table

Tags: php, sql

Hello I'm trying to update this scholarship application box. However when the year changed to 2013 it only displays scholarship applicant info from 2013. I'd like it to display info from 2012. I tried messing around with the date but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <?php
$appYear = date("Y").'-'.(date("Y")+1);
$sql = 'select * from sApplication where studentID = "'.$database->iPrep($_SESSION['ID']).'" AND appYear = "'.$appYear.'" LIMIT 1';
$appID = Scholarship::iFindSQL($sql);
$total = count($appID);
if ($total > 0)
    { 
        $app = array_shift($appID); 
    }
    else
        {
            $app = 0;
        }
?>
<li id="item-2">
  <div id="appStatus">
    <h3>Application Status</h3>
    <blockquote>
    <?php if ($app->submitted == ('0000-00-00') || !isset($app->submitted)) { ?> 

    <table style="border:1px solid #000;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><strong>Scholarship<br /> 2013-2014</strong></td>
    <td width="50" align="right"> <a style="font-size:16px;" href="welcome.php?   app=Scholar">Apply Now</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>References</strong></td>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Decision</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Scholarship 2012-2013</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Decision</strong></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    </table>



      <?php } else { ?> 
      <table style="border:1px solid #000;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">

        <tr>
          <td width="90%"><strong>Scholarship 2013-2014</strong></td>
          <td width="10%" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>
          <td align="right"><?=dbOutDate($app->submitted)?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>References</strong> </td>
          <td align="right"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <?php  
         $refs = Reference::iFindSQL("Select * from reference where appID = '".$app->ID."'");?>

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

         <?php foreach($refs as $ref) { ?>
         <tr> <td> <small><?php if($ref->rType == 'Academic Reference'){ echo 'Academic/Artistic/Professional'; } else { echo 'Community Service'; } ?></small></td> <td align="right"><?=$ref->status?></td></tr>
      <?php } ?>

        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Decision</strong></td>
          <td align="right">
         <?php
                if ($app->complete == 'Approved') { echo '<a   href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?app=Bank&appID='.$app->ID.'">Approved</a>'; }
                if ($app->complete == 'Declined') { echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?app=Declined&appID='.$app->ID.'">Declined</a>'; }
                if ($app->complete == 'Pending') { echo 'Pending'; }
                if ($app->complete == 'Incomplete') { echo 'Incomplete'; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the WHERE clause that limits the year.  Use ORDER BY to sort by year, descending.

```
$sql = 'select * from sApplication 
    where studentID = "'.$database->iPrep($_SESSION['ID']).
    '" ORDER BY appYear DESC LIMIT 1';
```